# Joomla 2.5 display articles by tag. Not in menu link

Tags: joomla-2.5, articles, tags

I wanted to display all articles tagged under a specific tag, inside an article (not a menu link). I know I can display articles by tag at the menu. But what I wanted is to know if it is possible to display those articles tagged inside another article.

**NOTE**: I don't want to display `tags`, but I want to display those articles tagged.

Example:

Under menu `web design` I have an article displaying a text and a brief explaining what it is, then after it, I would like to display all articles tagged under `design`.

How can I do this? Again, I didn't want to assign a menu to display those articles tagged under `design`.

Best regards.

Comment: Did 2.5 have tags?

Comment: Nope.Joomla 2.5 doesn't come with tags. You must be using a 3rd party component for tags or using 3.1 or higher?

Answer (score 1):

You could put the intro into a custom HTML module in position above the content and then do the normal component menu thing or you could use something like [Components anywhere](https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/componentsanywhere#free-vs-pro) to embed the content into an article if you really wish. But usually the module and normal menu item is the easiest solution. **IF** I understood what you want correctly, that is.